# How to use advanced custom field plugin as integrated library?

Tags: wordpress

I am new in WordPress. I know WordPress custom field plugin is an awesome staff. WordPress official documentation shows demo use just as plugin. I want to use this plugin to integrate with my theme.

But i don't know which files i have to call from my `functions.php` files

Any type of helps will be beneficial for me as i am novice in WordPress.Thanks

Comment: you don't have to call any files, just install the plugin, and then you will have to call the fields in the templates but that's it

Comment: But I don't want to use it as plugin. I want to use it a library.

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't think you can use acf in another way that with the plugin. Why don't you want to use the plugin?